# CopyPastor - Monitoring plagiarized posts on Stack Overflow

Tags: app, answers, duplicates

#### Background

[Guttenberg](http://stackapps.com/q/7197) is a chatbot which reports plagiarized posts on Stack Overflow. [CopyPastor](http://copypastor.sobotics.org/) is a web dashboard for Guttenberg. Guttenberg sends all the data upon detection of a plagiarized post and CopyPastor keeps a record of it permanently.

The main use of CopyPastor is to aid moderators to easily differentiate a plagiarized post, by providing a link to the  CopyPastor report in the flag text.

#### Present Features

- Keeps permanent records of reported posts, including their full text, author, and whether it was a plagiarism or a repost.
- Records feedback on each post (true positive and false positive), along with the user who provided the feedback.

#### Future ideas

The future thought is to utilize the API and add an ability to flag posts from the dashboard itself.

#### Source Code

CopyPastor is built using Python and Flask. The Source Code and the API documentation is present on Github: https://github.com/SOBotics/CopyPastor. Drop into the [SOBotics chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) to discuss anything related to it. The project is still work in progress, and any suggestions to improve are certainly welcome.

#### Sample Reports

Example of a clearly detectable report - http://copypastor.sobotics.org/posts/14

Example of a repost - http://copypastor.sobotics.org/posts/48

Example of a bad report - http://copypastor.sobotics.org/posts/10

---

<sub>The post has been written similar to the structure, and utilizes some words from [Sentinel](https://stackapps.com/questions/7127) Stack Apps post, which is another web dashboard.</sub>

Comment: The "Possible Plagiarism" and "Original Post" links use `target="_BLANK"` (wrong case) -- which causes the links to open in the *same* named window, not separate *new* windows.  This makes it very difficult to open both links simultaneously and is extremely annoying.  Should be `target="_blank"`. Except, forcing new windows/tabs is bad UI.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion @Brock, I'll create an [issue for that](https://github.com/SOBotics/CopyPastor/issues/22) and will update the code.

Comment: The server is returning a 503 error at the moment, is the dashboard offline already?

Comment: @Ferrybig the issue is fixed. Thanks for reporting.